# Fetching data from DB and setting it in xsd element tags

Tags: java, web-services, xsd

I am trying to fetch data from db and display it in my response in individual  tags .But I am not able to get the expected output . Please find the code which I am using for impl. Not able to find out what I am doing wrong.

**My Impl Code -**

```
AccountLoyaltyDetail loyaltyobj1 = new AccountLoyaltyDetail();
        List<AccountLoyaltyDetail> loyaltyobj = new ArrayList<AccountLoyaltyDetail>();
        AccountLoyaltyDetail loyaltyobjtemp = new AccountLoyaltyDetail();
    for (final Object[] records : resultList) {
                        String Journey_Id = assignStringRecordValue(records[2]);
                        // SET OBJECT VALUES
                        loyaltyobjtemp.setJourneys(Journey_Id);
                        loyaltyobj.add(loyaltyobjtemp);
                    }

                    loyaltyobj.add(loyaltyobj1);
```

**My pojo element-**

```
// This file was generated by the JavaTM Architecture for XML Binding(JAXB) Reference Implementation, v2.1.7-1.2.0.0_2-1-7-fcs 
// See <a href="http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxb">http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxb</a> 
// Any modifications to this file will be lost upon recompilation of the source schema. 
// Generated on: 2016.05.18 at 12:04:56 PM IST 
//


package com.fedex.marketing.loyaltyws.objects;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;


/**
 * <p>Java class for AccountLoyaltyDetail complex type.
 * 
 * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
 * 
 * <pre>
 * &lt;complexType name="AccountLoyaltyDetail">
 *   &lt;complexContent>
 *     &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
 *       &lt;sequence>
 *         &lt;element name="OperatingCompany" type="{http://fedex.com/ws/loyalty/v1}OperatingCompanyType" minOccurs="0"/>
 *         &lt;element name="Journeys" type="{http://fedex.com/ws/loyalty/v1}LoyaltyJourneyIdentifier"/>
 *         &lt;element name="Segments" type="{http://fedex.com/ws/loyalty/v1}LoyaltySegmentIdentifier"/>
 *       &lt;/sequence>
 *     &lt;/restriction>
 *   &lt;/complexContent>
 * &lt;/complexType>
 * </pre>
 * 
 * 
 */
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "AccountLoyaltyDetail", propOrder = {
    "operatingCompany",
    "journeys",
    "segments"
})
public class AccountLoyaltyDetail {

    @XmlElement(name = "OperatingCompany")
    protected OperatingCompanyType operatingCompany;
    @XmlElement(name = "Journeys", required = true)
    protected List<LoyaltyJourneyIdentifier> journeys = new ArrayList<LoyaltyJourneyIdentifier>();
    @XmlElement(name = "Segments", required = true)
    protected List<LoyaltySegmentIdentifier> segments = new ArrayList<LoyaltySegmentIdentifier>();

    /**
     * Gets the value of the operatingCompany property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link OperatingCompanyType }
     *     
     */
    public OperatingCompanyType getOperatingCompany() {
        return operatingCompany;
    }

    public List<LoyaltyJourneyIdentifier> getJourneys() {
        return journeys;
    }

    public void setJourneys(List<LoyaltyJourneyIdentifier> journeys) {
        this.journeys = journeys;
    }

    public List<LoyaltySegmentIdentifier> getSegments() {
        return segments;
    }

    public void setSegments(List<LoyaltySegmentIdentifier> segments) {
        this.segments = segments;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the operatingCompany property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link OperatingCompanyType }
     *     
     */
    public void setOperatingCompany(OperatingCompanyType value) {
        this.operatingCompany = value;
    }



}
```

**Actual output-**

```
        <LoyaltyDetails>
            <Journeys>FIRM_EMP_HERE_QTY|99</Journeys>
         </LoyaltyDetails>
         <LoyaltyDetails>
            <Journeys>FIRM_EMP_HERE_QTY|99</Journeys>
         </LoyaltyDetails>
```

**Expected Output-:**

```
<LoyaltyDetails>
              <LoyaltyDetails>
                <Journeys>FIRM_EMP_HERE_QTY|99</Journeys>
                <Journeys>FIRM_EMP_HERE_QTY|99</Journeys>
             </LoyaltyDetails>
```

**XSD**

```
<xs:complexType name="AccountLoyaltyDetail">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="OperatingCompany" type="ns:OperatingCompanyType"
                    minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="Journeys" type="ns:LoyaltyJourneyIdentifier>" />
                <xs:element name="Segments" type="ns:LoyaltySegmentIdentifier" />
            </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="LoyaltyJourneyIdentifier">
            <xs:sequence>
                  <xs:element name="JourneyIdentifierId" type="xs:string"
                        minOccurs="0">
                        <xs:annotation>
                              <xs:documentation>Free form text to be echoed back in the reply.
                                    Used to match requests and replies.</xs:documentation>
                        </xs:annotation>
                  </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>

</xs:complexType>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You need to create a List<AccountLoyaltyDetail> object within AccountLoyaltyDetail and annotate it as @XmlElement. This will create an infinite loop. It is not possible.



**POJOs:** 
@XmlRootElement
class AccountLoyaltyDetail {
    @XmlElement(name="journeys")
    private List<LoyaltyJourneyIdentifier> journeyList = new ArrayList<>();
    getters and setters...
}

@XmlRootElement
class LoyaltyJourneyIdentifier {
    @XmlElement
    private String journeyName;
    getters and setters.... 
}

**IMPL:**
AccountLoyaltyDetail loyaltytemp = new AccountLoyaltyDetail();
for (final Object[] records : resultList) {                 

                    LoyaltyJourneyIdentifier journey = new LoyaltyJourneyIdentifier();

                    String Journey_Id = assignStringRecordValue(records[2]);
                    // SET OBJECT VALUES
                    journey.setJourney(Journey_Id);     
                    loyaltytemp.setJourneyName(journey);

                } 
marshallerObj.marshal(loyaltytemp, ....)
```

Comment: How do I change it to to list .Can I use arrayList type directly here??

Comment: Thanks..what would be my xsd in this case ?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="AccountLoyaltyDetail">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="journeys" maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="LoyaltyJourneyIdentifier"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="LoyaltyJourneyIdentifier">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="journeyName" type="xs:string"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
 
</xs:schema>

Comment: It is giving error as" It was detected that 'LoyaltyJourneyIdentifier' has no namespace"..

Comment: Provide the POJOs please. In full.

Comment: added ..I have changed the type as expected one

Comment: Hi .. did you look